# angular ngFor access child method in parent

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an static variable in my child component (cannot being called directly). So I have a method that return this value.

Then in my parent I want to use *ngFor loop that needs to get a return of that method in the child.

I have no idea how could I access to it. Using @input for the method failed. Also alias did not work either

In the parent the code looks like this :

```
<app-item #items *ngFor="let item of items.getNumberOfInstants()"></app-item>
```

In the child code looks like this (I checked by removing @Input too for the method but it did not help) :

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input,Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() static NumberOfInstants:Array<any>=new Array(5);

  constructor() {
   }

   @Input() getNumberOfInstants():Array<number>{
     return ItemComponent.NumberOfInstants;
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems anti-pattern. Re-consider your approach.

Comment: if its static why dont you put your var on the parent level then pass in the things to display in the child with input them

Comment: Thanks. I prefer to have this static inside the child as I want to know what is the angular solution in such case rather than use work around solutions as Nilesh mentioned

Comment: you can't cycle a child's method in the parent... that conceptually doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: are you sure this code is working at all @Input() static what does it mean that should make a problem you shouldnt  use Input with static just create the static alone and then in the parrent component  read the variable from the ItemComponent you dont need to have an instance of the class to be able to read static property